# store variable in a memory address x86

Tags: assembly, x86

how to store variable in a memory address x86?

```
    LETTER DB ?
```

MOV [0X3100], LETTER

I tried the previous solution and it gives an error message:
wrong parameters

Comment: First load the variable into a register, then store that register to memory.

Comment: You must define the pointer type size, like byte, word, dword